# Drywall mud differences for taping, or gaps?

Tags: drywall, mudding

Just wanting to hear a second opinion besides from friends.  Are there any preferred products to use for taping versus filling screws and holes or gaps between sheets because framing is not square?  I am familiar with the general purpose mud and then something like easy sand 90 that comes in a bag.

What's the preferred product for filling the horizontal seams before taping?  And is it best to fill the gaps first, let that set up, then apply another thin coat with the tape embedded?

Comment: How big are the gaps?  What makes this different from a normal drywall procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Fill large gaps with Joint Compound.  Fill small seam crevices with Joint Compound and apply Seam Tape with joint Compound.  Keep Joint Compound below finish "grade" because it is difficult to sand.

Cover over the Joint Compound with Topping Coumpound which, is easily sanded and faired.

Answer (score 0):

The seams that are created when drywall panels are installed must be filled with 'joint compound' (or 'spackle, mud, compound,) and seam tape (paper or fiberglass) in order to produce a smooth flat surface. As far as there being or using specific types of compound for filling nail dimples and seams, you should use joint compound for both. Joint compound when it has set produces the hardest and strongest seam. Three layers of compound each applied wider than the other are the norm. If you want a highly smooth finish with no marks at all you can use a 'light weight' joint compound as a final or fourth coat. When dry it has a slight yellow tint that easily sands with a high grit paper. If the job needs to progress quickly, I will sometimes set the tape in a bed of mud, pressing it tightly to the surface and rather than wait for it do dry overnight will immediately cover it with a 6-8 inch wide layer of compound. Next day knock off any burrs or ridges and apply the second 10-12 inch layer, etc.